# Hide php echo output

Tags: php, ajax

i'm sending data to a javascript function from a php script with help of ajax.

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

The issue i'm having is that i'm running the php script right when the page loads, and the output is then displayed on the page, which I dont actually want to display. I tried to hide the echo with ob_end_clean() but this kinda breaks everything.

Comment: more details required. Are you requesting the same page with the ajax call? Also ajax is making a GET or POST? how you handle the call in page?

Comment: the page runs a js file that contains an ajax call of the type GET. What i'm actually doing is that the php script sends text comment from a db to this javascript file so it can display them on the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure you are making ajax request to same page, in that case you can check the request for ajax like this

```
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
   /* your ajax here code will go here */
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($rows);
   exit();
}

//non ajax code ...
...
```

that way `echo` will only run if its an AJAX call

Comment: +1 though I'd add `header('Content-type: application/json')` before and  `exit` right after echoing the JSON.